# preg_match ".com" except a number of certain domains

Tags: preg-match

Currently, I have this:

```
/(?<!gmail)\.com/
```

This preg_match all ".com" except "gmail.com".

The question is: how can I preg_match all ".com" except a number of certain domains like gmail.com, hotmail.com, yahoo.com, facebook.com, twitter.com?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(?<!gmail|hotmail|twitter|facebook|yahoo)\.com/
```